# obtener path de archivo con la uri,en android studio

Tags: java, android

Hola estoy haciendo una app con adnroid en java,lanzo una intent para pickear una imagen de galería. El método onActivityResult me devuelve la Uri de la imagen, pero necesito la ruta del archivo. Para poder mandarla por red a un servidor web con mysql.Googleando cómo puedo hacerlo, me ha remitido al siguiente método:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Log.i("indexCursor",cursor.getString(column_index));
        path=cursor.getString(column_index);
        return path;
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Según mi modesto conocimiento es una consulta a un content provider, pero no funciona, la variable int columnIndex queda nula. Sinceramente no entiendo bien que hace, y no se si tenga algo que ver sólo puse permiso READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
Creo que busca un entero con la posición MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA y nunca la encuentra. NO llego a imaginar cómo esa tabla tendrá organizadas las rutas a los archivos de imagen. ¿ Alguna idea de por qué no funciona o bien cómo si puedo conseguir la ruta de una imagen pickeada de galería?

Comment: El permiso READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE no es necesario, pero si WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, que sistema operativo estas usando?